# Converting webpack.config.js from 1.x to 2.x

Tags: webpack

The following is the modules section of my webpack.config.js file. I understand that `loaders` is now `rules` but how do I handle the query part?

This is the original 1.x version

```
module: {
   loaders: [
      {
         test: /\.jsx?$/,
         exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
         loader: 'babel',
         query: {
                  presets: ['es2015', 'stage-2', 'react']
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Here's what I have so far for the 2.x version:

```
module: {
   rules: [
      {
         test: /\.jsx?$/,
         exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
         use: 'babel-loader',
         options: {
            // I assume we now use options. How do I handle the presets?
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct [Options usage for babel-loader](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader#options)

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: [
            "es2015",
            "react",
            "stage-2"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I'd recommend either the above approach, or create a [.babelrc](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-react/#usage) file in your app root, with the below properties.

```
{
    "presets": [
        "es2015",
        "react",
        "stage-2"
    ]
}
```

Hope this helps.